# Flask-RESTful: Is it ok to have a class with a single function

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I saw a video, where classes with two functions( **init** and a regular one) were laughed about a lot, with a reason that If you do not have multiple functions do not opt for a class.
My API consists of a class with only a POST function, not even an **init** function.

```
class Singleclass(Resources):
      def post(self):
          do something
```

But, I can't write a function here as how would I import 'Resources' then.
Is the class above fine?

Comment: The `__init__` method will be inherited from `Resources` as maybe other methods defined there. It is completely fine to overwrite just one method in a subclass.

Comment: Oh Yesssss, Thank you sir. Totally forgot about that, my bad. Thanks for your reply, my doubts have cleared ;)